Is there any "incitement" type defence in copyright breach?
There is a paper that is cited in the Coders vs. Github Copilot case.

the judge cited the study's observation that Copilot reportedly "rarely emits memorized code in benign situations, and most memorization occurs only when the model has been prompted with long code excerpts that are very similar to the training data."

Would this prompting with long code excerpts be a defence in a "normal" copyright claim?  Given that one could demonstrate a breach of copyright by the creation of a derivative work if the prompt was short, would the fact that a derivative work was produced in response to "long code excerpts that are very similar to the training data" be any defence?

Surely the infringement occurred much earlier, when the copyrighted data was copied into the training database? The prompting had nothing to do with that; it simply served as a way to demonstrate later that the copyrighted data was there all along. Or am I misunderstanding what's being claimed?

@NateEldredge If the code was say GPL'ed just about anything but distributing derivative works is allowed without restrictions.  The linked article is all about charges that were thrown out prior to trial.  I think this was trained on GitHub code which was freely uploaded by the rights holders.


Would this prompting with long code excerpts be a defence in a
"normal" copyright claim?

No. As a comment by Nate Eldredge observes, the prompting with long code excerpts is just a way to prove an infringement that happened earlier. It isn't primarily about whether the immediate answer in response to the long prompt is an infringing derivative work.
For that matter, it could even be useful to prove that a non-infringing actions that the defendants deny occurred took place, in order to question their credibility generally about what happened in the training process. If the judge or jury (depending on how the case is tried) believes that the defendants are lying about how the model was trained in this respect, that goes a very long way towards finding that all of their statements about the training process are lies being used to cover up incriminating infringement in the training process.
The tactic of using a long prompt to ferret this out is similar to the tactic have having someone look for an intentional misspelling or fake data point in a source document that is improbably repeated in a copy. It is a tool to prove that something that cannot be directly observed actually happened.

In the linked case the code in question in open source, eg. GPL'ed.  I do not think this licence restricts the use of the code for training an AI at all.

@User65535 I know nothing about that particular case, but as this answer notes, the evidence could be relevant even if the use wasn't infringing.
